# how to find no of annotations of a specific chromosome (say chr10 that is in the chromosome's column)in a tab delimited file in linux

Tags: linux

for example 
my first line of the file when i filter the data using grep is as below. there are multiple entries of chr10 in the third column . How do i count the number of annotations of chromosome 10 (chr10).
I typed in 
$ grep "chr10" refseq-genes.txt | wc -w
i got teh below as answer. Is it correct. 
28528

$ grep "chr10" refseq-genes.txt | head -n 1
0       NM_138499       chr10   +       134210701       134231358       134210730       134219777       3       134210701,134218129,134230564,  134210855,134219793,134231358,       0       PWWP2B  cmpl    cmpl    0,2,-1,

Comment: I used 
$grep -o "chr10" refseq-genes.txt | wc -w
and i got 1783
this answer makes more sense to me. I want to confirm if this is correct.

Comment: I think it would help if you described your file format.  The example provided is hard to understand.

Comment: it is a bed file. It is a tab delimited file.

Comment: this format? https://genome.ucsc.edu/FAQ/FAQformat.html#format1

Comment: Sorry, still not clear which tokens are the important ones.  There's http://biology.stackexchange.com/ where people might have a better understanding of your subject material.